# Comparing categorical (demographic) data from two surveyed populations

Tags: categorical-data

I feel like this should be easier to answer - and maybe for someone else it is, but I don't do a ton of statistical work.

I'm comparing two different surveyed populations - one larger than the other - and I want to know if there is a significant difference in the racial and gender makeups of the groups. For example, group 1 is 81% white, while group 2 is 68% white. But the sample size of group one is 400, while group two is only 230.

I had planned to simply use graphs to demonstrate, but I would like to test difference. Any advice?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [MANOVA multiple comparisons with equivalence testing](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/141279/manova-multiple-comparisons-with-equivalence-testing)

Answer (score 1):

A chi-squared test of homogeneity should do the trick.  But don't abandon the graphs; you may need to explain your findings to someone who is statistics-averse.

Comment: Oh, I won't! I like the graphs. Thank you.